# Partition pruning while selecting multiple computed partition values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that is range partitioned on the integer representation of 3-character geohashes. I need to select multiple partitions from this table, however, the query is reading the whole table before giving me the required partitions.

Query:

```
WITH
  hashes AS (
  SELECT
    ['ezw',
    'ezx',
    'ezy',
    'ezz'] AS hash_list)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  hashes,
  UNNEST(hashes.hash_list) AS hash_str,
  `project.dataset.partitioned_table`
WHERE
  geohash_num = ABS(MOD(farm_fingerprint(hash_str),4000))
```

The three-character geohashes are in `hash_list`, and `abs(mod(farm_fingerprint(geohash),4000))` is how I get the numeric representation (<4000) of any geohash string.

The `project.dataset.partitioned_table` is partitioned on `geohash_num`, this column has numbers from 1 to 4000.

I would expect this query to fetch only the needed numeric partitions corresponding to the geohashes in `hash_list`, which would correspond to 961, 1234, 2684, 3606 but it reads all partitions before giving me the 4 needed partitions.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to have it read only the needed partitions and not the whole table?

**Clarification**:  This partition pruning works when I have only a single geohash,the following query reads only one partition and not the whole table, even though the `where` filter does not have a constant predicate :

```
WITH
  hashes AS (
  SELECT
    'ezw' AS hash_str)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  hashes,
  `freesolarcalc.Water_body_data.lake_geo33clustered_partitioned_dbscan`
WHERE
  geohash_num = ABS(MOD(farm_fingerprint(hash_str),4000))
```

The issue arises when I have to filter on multiple geohashes corresponding to multiple partition values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition pruning [works only with constant expressions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions).
You can select hash_str into variable and use it like `SET my_hash_str = (SELECT ...)` and then `... WHERE geohash_num = my_hash_str`

Comment: Would this mean that for my list of hashes, I need to make a different variable for each hash in the list, filter on each hash separately and then do a union all?

Comment: Yes. Probably `WHERE geohash_num IN (my_hash_str1, my_hash_str2, , my_hash_str3)` will work too.